# Laravel whereHas not getting any results?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, wherehas

I have a Restaurant Model, each restaurant has a Contact Model,
and each Contact is related to a City Model:

Restaurant.php:

```php
public function contact()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Contact','rest_id');
}
```

Contact.php:

```php
public function restaurant()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Restaurant','rest_id','id'); 
}

public function city()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

City.php:

```php
public function contacts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
}
```

now, what I want to do is search the restaurant names, alongside city names.
my controller code for searching is like this:

```php
// the purpose of this condition is to keep the query empty until applying desired filters
$data = Restaurant::where('id', '=', '0');
$cityRest=$request->cityRest ;
if (!empty($cityRest)) {

  $nameFilter = Restaurant::where('name', 'like', "%$cityRest%");

  $contactFilter = Restaurant::whereHas('contact', function ($contact) use ($cityRest) {

    $contact->where('address', 'like', "%$cityRest%");

    $contact->whereHas('city', function ($city) use ($cityRest) {
      $city->where('cityName', 'like', "%$cityRest%");
    });

  });

  $data = $data->union($nameFilter);
  $data = $data->union($contactFilter);
}

$data->get();
```

when searching for restaurant name,the results are returned correctly,but when searching for city names nothing is returned, although there is restaurants with contact models that has a city???

Comment: could you try using a `orWhereHas` instead of a `whereHas` inside your `contactFilter` e.g.:  `$contact->orWhereHas('city'...`

Comment: @Remul...wow, it actually worked!!

Comment: but why did it though??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `orWhereHas` instead of a `whereHas`.

With the `whereHas` you are searching for restaurants where the `contact.address` **AND** the `city.name` match your input.

By using the `orWhereHas` you are searching for restaurants where the `contact.address` **OR** the `city.name` match your input.

The AND and OR operators are used to filter records based on more than one condition:

- The AND operator displays a record if all the conditions separated by AND are TRUE.
- The OR operator displays a record if any of the conditions separated by OR is TRUE.

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Try this:

```php
$contactFilter = Restaurant::whereHas('contact', function ($contact) use ($cityRest) {

    $contact->where('address', 'like', "%$cityRest%");

    $contact->orWhereHas('city', function ($city) use ($cityRest) {
        $city->where('cityName', 'like', "%$cityRest%");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching `"%$cityRest%"` as string.

I think it should be like this:

```
Restaurant::where('name', 'like', "%".$cityRest."%");
```

Comment: review php for string interpenetration,I should give you a vote down,but I won't